# How to use a variable as an Object Key [MongoDB]

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use variable `name` given to me by my function, but its actually setting the `object key` equal to 'name'

```
    function addlist(name, item, id){ // Add to user's list
var $push = {}; $push[name] = item;
console.log(id);
db.collection('newcon').update({_id: id}, {"$push": {name: item}});
ret(id);
}
```

Other solutions similar to this don't work, since I need to also have it build onto the array every time this function is called, not replace whatever is in it each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has no nice notation for creating an object where the keys are variables:

```
var $push_query = {};
$push_query[name] = item;

... {"$push": $push_query} ...
```

Comment: This was a mistake on my end, thanks for the solution!